# Why are CRUD images sent to temp file?

Tags: php, laravel

In my Laravel application, I've created a page where I can add new books in a table, whenever I try to add or edit a new one, its photo is sent to the temp file although I've specified the saving path destination, what is the reason for that?

My functions:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
 $request->validate([
   'photo' => 'required',
   'parts' => 'required', 
   'writer_name' => 'required', 
   'title' => 'required', 
   'field' => 'required', 
   'photo' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
 ]);

 $input = $request->all();

 if ($photo = $request->file('photo')) {
   $destinationPath = 'uploads/books';
   $profileImage = date('YmdHis') . "." . $photo->getClientOriginalExtension();
   $photo->move($destinationPath, $profileImage);
   $input['photo'] = $profileImage;
 }
     
 Book::create($input);
      
 return redirect()->route('books.index')->with('success','Book inserted successfully.');
}
```

My index:

```
@foreach ($books as $book)
  <tr>
    <td><img src="uploads/books/{{ $book->photo }}" width="100px"></td>
    <td>{{ $book->copies }}</td>
    <td>{{ $book->note }}</td>
    <td>{{ $book->parts }}</td>
    <td>{{ $book->publication }}</td>
    <td>{{ $book->documentation }}</td>
    <td>{{ $book->review }}</td>
    <td>{{ $book->writer_name }}</td>
    <td>{{ $book->title }}</td>
    <td>{{ $book->field }}</td>
    <td>{{ $book->created_at }}</td>
    <td>{{ ++$i }}</td>
}
```

My model:

```
class Book extends Model
{
  use HasFactory;
  protected $fillable = [
    'photo', 'copies', 'note', 'parts', 'publication', 'documentation', 'review', 'writer_name', 'title', 'field', 'created_at'
  ];
}
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Did you tried this `$filePath = public_path('/uploads/books/');` Also remove two time validating the `photo` try to make it in one

Comment: @Nico Haase I've tried to redirect the image saving in another file (uploads/books), it stores the image there, but in the database it displays the temp destination.

Comment: Did you tried what i have provided

Comment: "but in the database it displays the temp destination" - where's the code that sets the final image path to the model?

Comment: @Rstdevelpzz I've tried, it doesn't work. What do you mean by the 2 time validating?

Comment: Check my answer now, you have used `'photo' => 'required'` two times into your validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer:

```
if(!empty($request->hasFile('photo'))){
     $image = $request->file('photo');
     $photoname = date('YmdHis').'.'.$image->extension();
     $filePath = public_path('/uploads/books/');
     $image->move($filePath, $photoname);
     $input['photo'] = $photoname;
            
     }
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. What did you change, and why?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in this way into your controller, it worked for me. Also why you are validating `photo` two times make it in one `'photo' => 'required|image|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png|max:2048'`

My previous answer

```
if(!empty($request->hasFile('photo'))){
$image = $request->file('photo');
$input['imagename'] = date('YmdHis').'.'.$image->extension();
$filePath = public_path('/uploads/books/');
$image->move($filePath, $input['imagename']);
$input['photo'] = $input['imagename'];
    
}
```

```
$name = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
 
$path = $request->file('image')->store('public/images');
 
 
$save = new Photo;
 
$save->name = $name;
$save->path = $path;
 
$save->save();
```

```
This line of code will upload an image into the images directory:
$path = $request->file('image')->store('public/images');
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. What did you change, and why?

Comment: @Rstdevelpzz how to use new Photo?

Comment: `new Photo` here `Photo` is your model name, at first make all the fields `nullable` into your validation also remove all other fields from model just try to upload only photo, your model name is `Book` check for it, what it shows you

Comment: @Rstdevelpzz do you mean that I have to make a new model named Photo that contains only photo? Doesn't that mean that I have to create a new table for photos only?

Comment: No what you made all is okay just remove all fields from model and keep only photo one, from your validation remove all validation and just keep the photo one, and then do as i have shown to you just in place of `new Photo` use your model that is `new Book`

Comment: @MohaSetif that was my previous answer you can mark it as right